# Websockets Read/Write

Tags: websocket, go

Go/websockets noob here.

I've modified [this working example](https://github.com/golang-samples/websocket/tree/master/simple) in such way that instead of

```
io.Copy(ws,ws)
```

I am doing

```
msg := []byte{}
_, err := ws.Read(msg)
_, err = ws.Write(msg)
```

(printing errors omitted for brevity)

To me it looks the same, but it does not work. It does not read anything (though does not return error either). And on the client side (Chrome/FF) I get "**WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state**" when trying to send second message.

In general, what is the approach for `read msg -> do something -> write msg` for ws in golang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When doing this, you read and write 0 bytes, you need to allocate an actual buffer size. And also, it needs to be within a loop.

ws.Read() will not allocate a buffer for you and will read only `len(msg)`, In your example, it is 0.

Cf io.Copy sources:

```
buf := make([]byte, 32*1024)
for {
       nr, er := src.Read(buf)
       if nr > 0 {
            nw, ew := dst.Write(buf[0:nr])
```